# UPPER and LOWER functions in Informix DB LIKE queries do not work with all entries in the table

Tags: sql, sql-like, informix

Background information:

- IBM Informix Dynamic Server Version 12.10.FC14WE
- DB_LOCALE=et_EE.utf8
- Table has an ID primary key, no indexes
- Column datatype lvarchar (-1)

The table column has names like "FIRST COMPANY", "SECOND COMPANY", "Third". To find name matches the UPPER function is being used. Example of the problem:

- `SELECT * FROM companies WHERE UPPER(name) LIKE 'FIRST%';` - gives no results
- `SELECT * FROM companies WHERE UPPER(name) LIKE 'SECOND%';` - gives expected result (SECOND COMPANY)
- `SELECT * FROM companies WHERE name LIKE 'FIRST%';` - gives expected result (FIRST COMPANY)
- `SELECT * FROM companies WHERE UPPER(name) LIKE 'FIRST%' OR name LIKE 'FIRST%'` - gives no results

What could cause this kind of behavior and how to solve it? Maybe entries in the same database table differ in some way?

Comment: I tried on the latest versions of 12.10 and 14.10 and LIKE works as expected. Could of questions: What's the exact version and platform of your 12.10?. Do you have an index on that table? What's the locale of the database?

Comment: @jsagrera, thanks for taking a look, I've updated the question with additional information. It's a weird problem, but hopefully someone has ideas what to check or what could potentially be wrong :)

Comment: well, still nothing. Tried on both engines with your Estonian locale (which I think could be the key) and the LIKE clause works as expected.  Can you try in a database created with the default locale (en_US.819) or one with 'en_US.UTF8'.  Do you have GL_USEGLU set? And one more: What do you get if you do "select name,'--'||upper(name)||'--' from company"?.

Comment: Don't have permissions in the current system for database creation and GL_USEGLU checking. The provided select query works as expected. I tested deletion, re-creation of the problematic entries which fixes them (updating all values had no effect). I can only guess that there is some sort of data corruption that is not directly visible and so far we have only noticed it causing issues with UPPER/LOWER LIKE queries.

Comment: If you still have some 'problematic' rows in the table, you can ask you DBA to check the actual info the data pages (e.g 'oncheck -pp stores7:company 256'). You should be able to see if there are any hidden characters or if there is anything strange with those particulars rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments of the question there is likely some sort of data corruption that can be fixed with deletion and re-creation of the problematic entries (updating had no effect). Since the system around this is rather complex and involves legacy technologies we did not dive deeper to figure out the root cause. Due to some other needs and considerations we instead created a separate column where company names are always in uppercase and adjusted necessary select queries to use that without the `UPPER` function.